# How do I take two elements and center them together using javascript, html, and/or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's an image:

[image]

What I want is that Chrysler image to be in the center of the box with `Sample size: 173918` at the top so it doesn't overlay the text. Here's the HTML.

```
<g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 40)">
   <g class="body-group">
      <image class="body-box" xlink:href="/static/fca%20block%20bg.png" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></image>
      <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(10, 0.6399999999999988) rotate(0, 90, 22.5)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 1; vertical-align: middle;">
         <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="13px" font-weight="400" x="90px" y="13px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; fill: white; text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px 1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 0px; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; opacity: 1;">Sample size: 173918</text>
      </g>
   </g>
   <g class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
      <image class="title-image" xlink:href="/static/checkmark.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
      <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto;">
         <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; fill: white; text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px 1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 0px; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Chrysler</text>
      </g>
   </g>
</g>
```

And here is the CSS.

```
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node.selected .body-group .body-box {
    cursor: inherit;
    pointer-events: none
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .d3plus-textBox,
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .body-group .body-box,
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .title-group .title-image {
   vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .title-group .d3plus-textBox text {
   vertical-align: middle;
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
    transform: translateY(0.15em)
}
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node.collapsed .body-group .body-box text {
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node.selected .body-group .body-box text {
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node .body-group .body-box {
    rx: 6;
    ry: 6
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node .title-group .title-image {
    rx: 10;
    ry: 10
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node .title-group text {
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
}
```

What I want is this-

[image]

[Here is the js-fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kc1ujh34/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the g element to svg and adjust the attributes `x` and `y` to make it work. In this case I set `x=50` and `y=-40`.

```
t.append("svg").classed("title-group", !0).attr("x", "50").attr("y", "-40").attr("transform", "translate(" + -o / 3 + ", " + (-s / 2 - r / 2) + ")")
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node.selected .body-group .body-box {
    cursor: inherit;
    pointer-events: none
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .d3plus-textBox,
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .body-group .body-box,
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .title-group .title-image {
   vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree .node .title-group .d3plus-textBox text {
   vertical-align: middle;
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
    transform: translateY(0.15em)
}
.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node.collapsed .body-group .body-box text {
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node.selected .body-group .body-box text {
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node .body-group .body-box {
    rx: 6;
    ry: 6
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node .title-group .title-image {
    rx: 10;
    ry: 10
}

.mitch-d3-tree.boxed-tree.default .node .title-group text {
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
    fill: white;
}
.title-image{
  position: relative;
z-index: 0;
left: 80px;
}
.sample{ position: relative;
z-index: 2;}
 .title-group {display:block; text-align: center;}
.body-box{
    position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 40)">
   <g class="body-group">
      <image class="body-box" xlink:href="/static/fca%20block%20bg.png" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></image>
      <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(10, 0.6399999999999988) rotate(0, 90, 22.5)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 1; vertical-align: middle;">
         <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" class="sample" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="13px" font-weight="400" x="90px" y="13px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; fill: white; text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px 1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 0px; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; opacity: 1;">Sample size: 173918</text>
      </g>
   </g>
   <g class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
      <image class="title-image" xlink:href="/static/checkmark.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
      <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto;">
         <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" class="sample" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; fill: white; text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px -1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px 1px 0px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 0px; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Chrysler</text>
      </g>
   </g>
</g>
```

and i don't understand what you mean " doesn't overlay the text"?

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want the image and text Chrysler to be on top of the text that says sample size. I want it to look pretty.

Comment: This didn't answer the question. It actually made the whole program fail...

Comment: your description is incomplete and confusing , please send screenshot that you want

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/MWYjQvK check this , i cant see your images so i put margin-top:-10px; you can adjust for yourself

Comment: That didn't work. I put a link to the js-fiddle up there so you can play around with it.